# Setting the Cursor Position in a Win32 Console Application

Tags: c++, console-application, cursor-position

How can I set the cursor position in a Win32 Console application?  Preferably, I would like to avoid making a handle and using the Windows Console Functions.  (I spent all morning running down that dark alley; it creates more problems than it solves.)  I seem to recall doing this relatively simply when I was in college using stdio, but I can't find any examples of how to do it now.  Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

**Additional Details**

Here is what I am now trying to do:

```
COORD pos = {x, y};
HANDLE hConsole_c = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer( GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER, NULL );
char * str = "Some Text\r\n";
DWDORD len = strlen(str);

SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole_c, pos);
WriteConsole(hConsole_c, str, len, &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
CloseHandle(hConsole_c)
```

The text string `str` is never sent to the screen.  Is there something else that I should be doing?  Thanks.

Comment: Good question, which is why I'm in this post, this was so easy to do in Turbo Pascal on pre-graphics card PCs (XT, AT and 386) even as a high school student, as a final assignment, I was able to create an interface to enter details into a fictitious ticket booking system... and got an A+, why is it so difficult now?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See [SetConsoleCursorPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686025(VS.85).aspx) API

**Edit:**

Use WriteConsoleOutputCharacter() which takes the handle to your active buffer in console and also lets you set its position.

```
int x = 5; int y = 6;
COORD pos = {x, y};
HANDLE hConsole_c = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer( GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER, NULL);
SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(hConsole_c);
char *str = "Some Text\r\n";
DWORD len = strlen(str);
DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;
WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(hConsole_c, str, len, pos, &dwBytesWritten);
CloseHandle(hConsole_c);
```

Comment: `SetConsoleCursorPosition` is a Windows Console Function, which I stated that I would like to avoid using.

Comment: So, I ended up going with Hans suggestion of using `GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)` to get the handle to the existing console, but it turned out that I needed to use `WriteConsoleOutputCharacter()` as well.  I don't know why that call does the trick, but it's working now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

Using the console functions, you'd use `SetConsoleCursorPosition`. Without them (or at least not using them directly), you could use something like `gotoxy` in the [ncurses](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/ncurses.htm) library.

Edit: a wrapper for it is pretty trivial:

```
// Untested, but simple enough it should at least be close to reality...
void gotoxy(int x, int y) { 
    COORD pos = {x, y};
    HANDLE output = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(output, pos);
}
```

Comment: The `gotoxy` is what I had in mind, but I found that even though the `SetConsoleCursorPosition` API does correctly set the cursor position, when I attempt to send text to the console using `printf`, the text is output to the location the cursor was at prior to calling the API.

Comment: @Jim: It would be interesting to know what compiler does that. I've used code like this with Microsoft's compiler for years, and never seen the behavior you describe.

Comment: Please see the addtional details that I've added to the question.  Thanks.

Comment: @Jim: you're creating and writing to a screen buffer (basically just a block of memory), but not writing to the console itself, or associating the screen buffer you created with the console.

Comment: Jerry, thanks for the suggestions.  I ended up writing a wrapper class to handle all the console manipulation.

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, you forgot to call `SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer`.  What exactly was the point of creating your own?  Use `GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)` to get a handle to the existing console.

Answer (score 1):

You were probably using [ANSI excape code sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), which do not work with Windows 32-bit console applications.

Comment: Hmmm, that's a possibility.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream.h>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int x,y;
  cin>>x>>y;
  SetCursorPos(x,y); //set your co-ordinate
  Sleep(500);
  mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0); // moving cursor leftdown
  mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,x,y,0,0); // moving cursor leftup //for accessing your required co-ordinate
  system("pause");
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Need more information. There is no method called SetCursorPos.

Comment: @GavinWilliams  Method was present in win 7 don't know about win 10