# C++ Overwrite output numbers in a For loop.

Tags: c++

C++ Overwrite output numbers in a For loop. output = always 1 line of overwriting numbers counting up to 10. Basically LIVE number counting up. idk how to explain this ill show a .gif file to explain what i'm trying to do.  http://images49.fotki.com/v1555/photos/2/292835/1608389/15animation-vi.gif

Comment: Please be more specific. For example, output to where?

Comment: Try using system("cls") or system("clear") (depending on your OS) to clear the screen after printing each number.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732292/setting-the-cursor-position-in-a-win32-console-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the question needs further clarification but if you want to output numbers in a growing fashion to a console, you can use carriage return after each iteration and then sleep

the following example demonstrates how to do it in ubuntu using stdio and unistd:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    for(;i < 10; ++i)
    {
        printf("\b%d", i);
        fflush(stdout);
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I think [SetConsoleCursorPosition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686025(v=vs.85).aspx) is what you're looking for.