# How to split c++ console screen into parts?

Tags: c++, console

I'm making a c++ console application, I want to split the console screen into parts and every part will print an individual output, to be more clear the console screen should be close to the design of **Far Manger** console app screen, but I have no idea how to start and what libraries should I use to do so. Sorry if it's a naive question but I seriously have no idea and couldn't find what I want when I made a search.

Comment: I don't know if most consoles even support that splitting the window. I doubt they do. You'll probably need to find a console that supports this, then use their API.

Comment: What operating system(s) are you targeting? (There could be workarounds for this, e.g. like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732292/setting-the-cursor-position-in-a-win32-console-application) on Windows).

Answer (score 1):

If you want control of console text, such as positioning, or representation in a windowed fashion, have a look at [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/).

Your target system may support escape sequences (see the wiki [ANSI Escape Codes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)), or have particular API (as mentioned in the above comments) to implement console manipulation.