# Recoloring text in an existing .NET Console line

Tags: .net, console

I have a .NET console application that uses a little bit more than just Console.WriteLine - I write things to different parts of the current line, as processing progresses.

I want to change the color of all the characters in the line before moving on to the next line (so that the current line is in white, and all previous lines are in gray).

How can I change the color of existing characters in the console, without printing them again?

Answer (score 0):

You probably can't do it that way. If you have already printed a symbol, you will not be able to change its color.

Possible solution is to do like @Arvindsinc2 says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43310466/how-to-change-colour-of-previously-printed-text-in-the-console). Just flush line and rewrite it again with additional info.

Hope this would help