# Move cursor using keypress

Tags: c

How to move cursor using keypress , without using goto in C?

Like I want to a program to move the cursor using keypress W , A , S , D (W for move up , A for move left , S for move down and D for move left)

Comment: OS?  Targeted terminal emulator (if any)?

Comment: There's no "standard API".  The "goto" keyword has nothing to do with cursor control.  There are many platform-specific options (for example, Win32, if you happen to be running a command prompt in Windows).  STRONG SUGGESTION: consider the open source, cross-platform [ncurses](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/) library.

Answer (score 0):

goto doesn't help you here. In fact, the code for controlling a desktop computer's mouse is much more complicated.

Often it's not portable either.

For example: In Windows in Visual Studio, we can use functions from Microsoft's Win32API. This guy already gave an answer (the code is messy):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2732323/7753444